# how to make validation rule for a field if another field is not empty in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two input field one is **startDate** input field and another is **endDate** input field.I want to make validation rule such that if  **startDate** field is not empty than **endDate** should not be empty and vice versa.So How to make validation rule for that.Below is the validation I have put on it

```php
'startDate' => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y' ],
'endDate'   => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y', 'after_or_equal:startDate' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Method is**

```
 request()->validate([
  'startDate' => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y' ],
  'endDate'   => [ 'required_with:startDate', 'date_format:d-m-Y', 'after_or_equal:startDate' ]
]);
```

**Second Method**

```
 request()->validate([
        'startDate' => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y' ],
        'endDate'   => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y', 'after_or_equal:startDate' ]
    ]);
    if(!empty(trim(request("startDate")))){
      request()->validate([
        'startDate' => [ 'required', 'date_format:d-m-Y' ],
        'endDate'   => [ 'required', 'date_format:d-m-Y', 'after_or_equal:startDate' ]
       ]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
request()->validate([
  'startDate' => [ 'nullable', 'date_format:d-m-Y' ],
  'endDate'   => [ 'required_with:startDate', 'date_format:d-m-Y', 'after_or_equal:startDate' ]
]);
```

For reference check Laravel docs [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-with)